# how to add a plugin Cordova-vk in Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I want to use this plugin in my app
[plugin cordova-vk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-vk)

but I can't connect it to typescript.

```
vkSdk is not defined
```

I understand that it does not locate the plugin. He is in the node_modules folder. How do I connect it to my page?
And use his methods.

I tried to prescribe

```
declare let cordovaVk : any;
```

but it didn't help. I know I'm doing something wrong. But I can't figure out what it was.
I'm using the latest versions of Cordova and Ionic since I just started the project

Answer (score 1):

According to the [plugin.xml](https://github.com/akveo/cordova-vk/blob/master/plugin.xml) of the specified plugin:

```xml
 <js-module src="www/vksdk.js" name="VkSdk">
        <clobbers target="VkSdk" />
 </js-module>
```

The global variable is `VkSdk`.

In your ts file declare it immediately below the import statements.

```
declare var VkSdk:any;
```

Also while calling the plugin, make sure it is inside `platform.ready()`

```
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
     VkSdk.init('123456');//from the plugin docs
})
```

Also Cordova plugins need to be tested in a device or emulator.. cordova is not supported in Ionic serve

Comment: now I get this message: "
Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: VkSdk is not defined"

Comment: which platform are you running this?

Comment: currently trying to test through a browser (ionic serve)

Comment: Cordova plugins need to be tested in a device or emulator.. cordova is not supported in Ionic serve